# How to send file/Image from One Ftp server to another via python coding?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I had One Image that is stored on one FTP.I want to move or copy it to another FTP.
I had use `storbinary` function. `storbinary(command, file)`.
Here file is the actual file which need to open. `file = open('/image/abc.jpg','rb')`.
But while opening this file i got this error
 `---IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`.
It is working fine when i want to upload an image from Local Pc to ftp,but with 2 ftp it fails.
The main issue is the open function.

Comment: Have you considered using subprocess calls?

Comment: please elaborate on it.

Comment: If you're able to complete the process through command line, then all you have to do is translate those commands into python subprocess calls. While this may be considered as poor practice, you can execute all shell commands within python.